# How to create a panel for admin to change some contents in HTML?

Tags: html, panel

My question is this. There are some texts,reports written on the webpage under the div tag. This text should be changed once a week. But, the person who is updating can't use the simple copy and paste because, when he do that the whitespaces, enters are ignored. So, my purpose is creating a panel to change only that part of webpage with proper design. Is there any way to do it. Or is there anyway that the copy and paste text works properly.

```
an example : 

1-)John is going to work today.
2-)Michael is at home.

But when we copy and paste this to html code under the div tag, result is:


1-)John is going to work today.2-)Michael is at home.
```

I hope i could make myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the new content in a PRE tag. E.g.

```
<pre>
1-)John is going to work today.
2-)Michael is at home.
</pre>
```

It will keep the formatting of the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that they are within a `<div>` the problem is that they are in the same paragraph. Markup like

```
 <div><p>
 1-) John</p><p>
 2-) Michael</p>
 </div>
```

or even

```
 1-) John<br/>
```

would likely work. I put the `<div>` in to show that it doesn't matter. A div is a "flow" which lets the browser break lines when it needs to without copy-pastable breaks. `<p>` and `<br/>` tags break the flow.

Comment: yes but,  the problem is the new coming admin don't know about the br tags and also don't have time for this. I was designer of this webpage and now i'm leaving the job, so new admin should change the content without getting involved with html tags you know.

Comment: This is why i'm asking a panel kinda thing.

Comment: Then leave them with Markdown or a Wiki. People who can't handle HTML shouldn't be touching HTML.

Comment: @LuckySlevin - If you need to update this via a panel, then you need to write both server and client code. The alternative is to teach the new person how to use a WYSIWYG editor, such as Dreamweaver.